# How can I alter the value of a field in views?

Tags: views, commerce

In my process to rewrite the quantity widget field on every page of the commerce process I ran into another issue. I have successfully altered the quantity widget textfield into a dropdown in the shop and on the cart page using the `hook_form_alter()`. on `commerce_cart_add_to_cart_form_` **($form['quantity'])** and `views_form_commerce_cart_form_default` **($form['edit_quantity']**.

On my checkout summary I see that the quantity is again 0.1 instead of 100 grams. But when I checked with `dpm($form_state)` I saw that the `commerce_checkout_form_checkout` generates HTML under the cart_contents_view instead of hookable $forms..

[image: cart_contents_view]

How should I alter the output of the field on this page?

Best Regards